# How to update a string in a file based on another string in the same file using perl

Tags: string, perl, file, edit

I have file which has the following content:

```
1.this is raman
2.loves getting up early
3.had a bad morning
4.this is raman
5.loves getting up early
6.had a bad morning
7.this is franck
8.loves getting up late
9.had a bad morning
```

I want to search a string "raman". If string "raman" is found successfully , then i want to replace a string "bad" by "good" which is present after 2 lines from the line in which String "raman" was found.

Here is my reference code....

```
open FILE, "+<$reference_file" or die $!;
my @lines = <FILE>;
my $count = 0;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    chomp($line);
    $count++;
    if ( $line =~ m/raman/ ) {
        print $line;
        last;
    }

}

close(FILE);
```

Comment: Do you just want to do that for the first incidence of 'Raman'?

Comment: no i want to do that for second instance as well

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_LINE_NUMBER) and a state variable to keep track of the last line that `/raman/` was seen on.

The following demonstrates with some test data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# open my $fh, '+<', $reference_file;
my $fh = \*DATA;

my $last_raman = -1e8;

while (<$fh>) {
    $last_raman = $. if /raman/;
    s/bad/good/ if ($. - $last_raman) == 2;
    print;
}

__DATA__
1.this is raman
2.loves getting up early
3.had a bad morning
4.this is raman
5.loves getting up early
6.had a bad morning
7.this is franck
8.loves getting up late
9.had a bad morning
```

Outputs:

```
1.this is raman
2.loves getting up early
3.had a good morning
4.this is raman
5.loves getting up early
6.had a good morning
7.this is franck
8.loves getting up late
9.had a bad morning
```

For editing a file, I would recommend using [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPLACE_EDIT) as demonstrated in [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

Comment: code looks good....but i am facing trouble while using the file handling stuff. If possible please help :)

Comment: The linked resource provides a lot of examples for exactly how to do what you want.  Try them, and if you have issues, post a new problem.